# Nevron Open VISION Evaluation

Tags: macos, xamarin, monomac, nevron

I was reviewing the NOV for Mac OS X development, in my way I found that they have Nevron Writer for Mac, which is built using their SDK (did any one find the Visio-like application for Mac?), and it seems there is a huge problem in performance and rendering. They mentioned that they are supporting native look and feel, but Writer UI rendering is for sure not native. Is it achieving portability by sacrificing native rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full Disclosure:  I work for Nevron

The Nevron Draw product is about to be released in the next couple of weeks, but is currently not available for download although the version is already built. We are now updating the Nevron Office site ([www.nevronoffice.com](https://www.nevronoffice.com/)) and it will soon contain information and downloads for Nevron Draw.

**Regarding performance and rendering.** What machine are you running the program on? NOV UI for Mac is very fast and in many aspects I would even say faster than native Mac UI controls.

**Regarding native look and feel.** We do not use native controls in NOV – the look and feel is made to resemble Mac via CSS. We are going to release a new and updated Mac theme very soon. There are many reasons for which we do not use native controls, including:

- Portability  - native controls are not portable and we support a large set of integration platforms. Achieving 100% single code base for Windows, Mac and other platforms is impossible with AWT like toolkits that use native controls.
- Common denominator problem – the more platforms that you support means that toolkits that use native controls will suffer features, as all controls are very different on each platform. NOV UI is on the other hand very feature rich and we provide identical functionality for all users on all platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I am using a Mac Book Pro, and the App wasn't responsive. On that machine I'm running Xamarin too  (Commercial version of Mono). CSS will never be as good and as fast as native controls, this was proven by many frameworks out there. I am not criticising here, I just wanted to validate my assumption. I will be waiting for the launch to get my hands on the evaluation for testing.

Comment: Hi, I would like to inform you that the new version of Nevron Open Vision (2016.1) is now available on [Nevron's website](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision.aspx). Updates to the [Nevron Office apps](https://www.nevronoffice.com/) have also been published, so you can take a look at them, too if you want. They are much more stable on the Mac now.